# Let $A \subseteq B$ be dense in $B$. Show that the closure $\overline A = B$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

### An incomplete attempt

If $A$ is dense in $B$,
we can approximate the members of $B$
arbitrarily well with elements of $A$.
In other words,
for every $b \in B$ and $\varepsilon > 0$
there exists an $a = a(\varepsilon) \in A$,
for which $\Vert b - a(\varepsilon)\Vert < \varepsilon$.

#### ''$\subseteq$''

Now let $x \in \overline A$,
meaning either $x \in A$, or $x$
is an accumulation point of $A$.
Every element of $A$  is contained in $B$,
so we only need to worry about the accumulation points.

Let $x_a$ then be an arbitrary accumulation point of $A$.
Therefore there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subset A$,
that converges towards $x_a$.
But as each $x_n \in A$,
and $A$ is dense in $B$,
each $x_n$ is arbitrarily close to
a certain
$b_n \in B$.
Then the norm 
$\Vert b_n - x_n \Vert < \varepsilon$.

Therefore the sequence $(b_n) \to x_a$ as well,
making $x_a$ an accumulation point of $B$, as well as $A$.
As $B$ is closed, it contains all of its accumulation points,
resulting in  $\overline A \subseteq B$.

#### ''$\supseteq$''

Let $y\in B$.
As $B$ is closed,
it contains all of its accumulation points $x_b$,
and we can find a sequences $(b_n)$
that converge toward said points.
We also know that $A \subseteq B$, so every $a \in A$ is also in $B$.

But then what? I can't immediately think of a way to include $B$ in the closure $\overline A$ with these facts.

Comment: Is $B$ the normed space that you are working with? Or is it just a subset of that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bar A \supset B$: Consider an arbitrary $y$ in $B$.  In the case that $y \in A$, we are done.  Otherwise, $A$ is dense in $B$, so for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x \in A$ with $\|x - y\| < \epsilon$.  Thus, for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$, we may select an element $x_n \in A$ such that $\|x_n - y\| < 1/n$.

We see that $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $y$, which means that $y$ is an accumulation point of $A$.  Thus, $y \in \bar A$.